# XPath: Find a node with two conditions

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I got this XML:

```
<iet:aw-data>
  <iet:metadata filter=""/>
  <iet:message-resource>
    <iet:message>תוכניות אחרות שאינן פדראליים</iet:message>
    <iet:customer id="1"/>
    <iet:code>edi.claimfilingindicator.11</iet:code>
    <iet:locale>iw_IL</iet:locale>
  </iet:message-resource>
  <iet:message-resource>
    <iet:message>ספק מועדף הארגון (PPO)</iet:message>
    <iet:customer id="1"/>
    <iet:code>edi.claimfilingindicator.12</iet:code>
    <iet:locale>iw_IL</iet:locale>
  </iet:message-resource>
  .
  .
  .
</iet:aw-data>
```

I want to build an expression to get all the nodes with `code` and `message` which contains a given parameter for each one of them.

What I made so far is this expression:

```
String exp = "//*[local-name()='message-resource']//*[local-name()='code'][contains(text(), 'edi')]"
```

Now I want to add the `message` field as another condition to this expression and I need help with that.

Comment: What do you mean on "all the nodes"? All matching messsage-resource nodes?

Comment: yes, like a SQL query which have one condition that related for two nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subpath as a predicate. Assume you want to select `code`s of message resources where `message` contains 'some message substring':

```
//*[local-name()='message-resource' and ./*[local-name()='message' and contains(text(), 'some message substring')]]//*[local-name()='code'][contains(text(), 'edi')]
```

Comment: Not working.. getting an error - `javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: misquoted literal... expected single quote!`

Comment: Yeah, missed a single quote. I've edited the answer, so it's fixed now.

Comment: Works! Thanks! is there an chance that you could please update it to search with ignore case (and also contains) ?

Comment: There's no standard XPath 1.0 function to change the string case as far as I'm aware (`translate()`-hack doesn't seem to be a way to go to me) . It may be available in your environment, but I'm not familiar with java xpath tools/libs. There's `upper-case()` and `lower-case()` functions in XPath 2.0 though, so use those if you can.

Answer (score 0):

My version

```
//*[local-name()='message-resource']/*[local-name()='code' and contains(text(), 'edi')]/../*[local-name()='message' and contains(text(), 'PPO')]/..
```

Just replace 'PPO' to what you are searching for in message.